# Plot Piecewise-Smooth Vector Field.

Tags: plotting, vector

I want to plot a piecewise-smooth vector field. For instance:

$F_1(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2, y^2)$,
$F_2 (x,y) = (2xy,2xy-x^2)$ and $H(x,y) = x-y$

$F(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
F_1(x,y) \text{ if } H(x,y) >0 \\
F_2(x,y) \text{ if } H(x,y)<0
\end{cases}$

How can I plot $F(x,y)$ in Mathematica?

Comment: Try `Piecewise`+`VectorPlot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f1[x_, y_] := {x^2 + y^2, y^2}
f2[x_, y_] := {2 x y, 2 x y - x^2}
h[x_, y_] := x - y

f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{f1[x, y], h[x, y] >= 0}, {f2[x, y], h[x, y] < 0}}]

VectorDensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, VectorStyle -> Directive[Red], 
                           VectorScale -> Large, ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
                           ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[Sign@h[#, #2]] &)
                 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kuba. It is exactly what I was looking.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result with Mathematica 10.4.  See [115620](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115620/1063)  Can you?  Thanks.